# how to get the value of array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

```
$ols_produk = $this->db->query("SELECT files FROM galeri_files WHERE id_galeri = '$id'");
    $file = $ols_produk->result();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($file);

    echo "</pre>";

    if($file != ''){
        foreach ($file as $key=>$value) {
            unlink('gambar/galeri/'.$key);
        }
    }
```

when i look in `print_r($file);`the result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [files] => g+.png
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [files] => andbook.pdf
        )
)
```

and i cant unlink the file because it select the number of array,
how to get the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you $files is an array of objects, foreach will get the value as object, and use -> to access the member as this:

```
foreach ($file as $v) {
    unlink('gambar/galeri/'.$v->files);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($file as $key=>$value) {
    unlink('gambar/galeri/'.$value['files']);
}
```

Comment: still can't. it says "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Answer (score 0):

Like this.Use codeigniter's `result_array()` result set to get the values in array format from database.

```
$ols_produk = $this->db->query("SELECT files FROM galeri_files WHERE id_galeri = '$id'");
    $file = $ols_produk->result_array();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($file);

    echo "</pre>";

    if(count($file)>0){
        foreach ($file as $key=>$value) {
            unlink('gambar/galeri/'.$value['files']);
        }
    }
```

For more see [Codeigniter Result Sets](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)